# A few students requesting to cancel lectures due to their personal reasons. What should I do?

Tags: teaching, lecture-teaching-method, workshop

I give lectures to postgraduate students. The number of students in this batch is very low (< 20). The lectures are foundation lectures for the course. We are only into the basics of the course.

A few (maybe 4) students of this batch are requesting to cancel two lectures as they won't be available for personal reasons. In fact, they are going to attend a workshop. In my university, attending workshops that are not fully recommended by the department is considered 'personal interest'.

One option is to ignore their request and ask them to study the topics covered during the lectures or with the help of students present during the lectures. If they could study these topics themselves or with friends, they wouldn't have requested me to cancel these lectures.

**What should I do in this case?**

I could ask this question to my head of the department, but, I don't know how this will turn out for students. They should not feel that they were not allowed by the head to attend this workshop.

I do understand that there will be variations of opinions on my question as per the different academic rules of universities but I still want some insights from experienced academicians.

Comment: Is the personal reasons due to timing conflict or some other reason? In one of my postgrad classes that I attended, there was a timing conflict for a significant number of the class, and the lecturer rescheduled that lecture. Not sure how to solve other reasons.

Comment: Is attendance of the lectures mandatory?

Comment: Other than being mandatory, are the students allowed to skip a few classes? In some places you automatically fail a class if you skip more than x% of lectures. IF the students need to reschedule because they've already spent their allowed absences, this changes things.

Comment: But is it reasonably possible to accommodate this one? Would there actually be any logistical problem with rescheduling e.g. number of spare weeks till midterm/finals decreases? I would actually bring that up in class and flip the question back to them: *"If we reschedule n weeks, then we have n weeks fewer slack in the schedule for makeup classes/revision. Is the class ok with that?"* I get the whole *"If we do this for them once, we will have to do it in future..."* argument, but explaining the scheduling also helps explain why you can't and aren't obligated to do it henceforth in general.

Comment: I'm curious in what fields <20 is considered very low

Comment: @Mast No, attendance is not mandatory.

Comment: I had to take a call. I took the lectures finally. But, amount of attention this question has got is surprising. I learned a lot from comments and answers. It's really helpful.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

If you do this for a minority, then you will have to do it every time a few students have some excuse.

I suggest that you don’t consider this and make it clear that if they miss lectures then it is up to them to catch up on material.

Providing double or triple repeats of lectures due to a few absences, especially if unpaid, is not a good use of your time.

Some students will want to rationalize their choices and make sure which they attend - some workshops can be valuable. If you think one workshop is very worthwhile then you could consider re-scheduling for all, but that depends on your schedule, and yes, I have done this for similar reasons involving the majority.

Based on a comment>
I always provide the material used in class - notes & worked example on Moodle as well as further practice problems (some 10 to 20 for each topic with solutions) for those who attend as well as those who do not.

Comment: +1. Yes, I fully understand. I am thinking too much from the student's side.

Comment: @Coder: Don't let it stop you from encouraging students to attend non-mandatory classes/workshops, even if you cannot make any accommodations for them in your own class. (From your statement "They should not feel that they were not allowed by the head to attend this workshop.", I gather that you are generally in favour of their wanting to attend the workshop, if it weren't for the schedule collision with your class.)

Comment: Also, you could offer to send them course notes to cover the lecture? I'm not saying you should put extra work in here, just any notes you may have already written in preparing the lecture

Comment: @Bee I provide the notes, worked example and further practice questions on Moodle for those who do, and do not, attend without fear or favour.

Comment: I don't know how OP stands with technology, but providing a video capture of the lecture is quite common at my Uni, that way they'd have literally everything available that the attending students have

Comment: @Hobbamok that is not standard practise everywhere... some do, some don’t. However, I have seen that videos cannot spot simple errors on a student’s file and if you made a video containg every possible error it would be hours and hours long which may defeat the point. Students say that they look at youtub videos and find them good or bad... And, following a bad video can affect them for a long time...

Comment: @SolarMike yeah, thats why I mentioned my uni (and even there its just my and 2 other departments), and my point was that they then have the profs original statements + other students questions  + they can still write their own questions via email. Yes its still more work for them than for the attending student but hey, they're skipping class after all. [I know video footage is not perfect, but depending on the prof/subject and general interactivity sometimes quite close to live]

Comment: @Hobbamok I teach excel, so when they have an error in their workbook they can get help in class but not outside so easily and, no, I don’t expect 180 students all sending me files to correct...

Comment: I owuld add that in the past as I've found it extremely annoying as a student when a group of students get together and try and get lectures moved / changed etc. It often results in the rescheduled lecture being moved to a date that is not inconvientent to the remainind students - this has happend to me and the response was "well I've already moved it once, I cannot keep moving it everytime someone asks me to". So remember there may be students who do want to attend

Answer (score 32):

There is really no need to do this. Lecture is an efficient way for a single person to help a group to learn, but it isn't the most effective way for an individual to learn material. There are other ways to learn the material and they need to become familiar with them. Books, notes, discussions, but most important, exercises to make the material part of their deep learning.

Point them to alternative sources if you like. And maybe some exercises, also. It is very unlikely that such sources don't exist. But learning is *their* responsibility. Your responsibility is to provide the environment in which learning can occur.

Moreover the request shouldn't result in impeding the learning of the rest of the class.

Comment: It's fine as well to encourage the students to attend their workshop—that's probably a great use of their time. But that choice comes with some consequences to their other obligations (your course for example), and they're the ones that need to accomodate the choice, not you (the OP).

Comment: "Lecture is an efficient way for a single person to help a group to learn" False.

Comment: @anonymous physicist Quite obviously true.

Answer (score 9):

From the comments:

> I provide the notes, worked example and further practice questions on Moodle for those who do, and do not, attend without fear or favour.

If they choose to attend a workshop instead of your class, they are still receiving the material so are not at a disadvantage (other than missing out on what I'm sure is a superb lecture).

They are making the choice to go to this workshop, it's not compulsory. I think that you therefore have no ethical obligation to provide them anything more. When I was at university many lecturers would only provide notes to those who attended or didn't provide notes at all, regardless of your reasons.

You sound like a fair lecturer who wants the best for their students, but don't let them take advantage of your kind nature. I would respond with:

> All material covered in the lecture will be available in the lecture notes in the usual format, I will therefore not be cancelling or repeating the lecture, but understand your decision to not attend on this occasion. Please feel free to ask next class if there is anything from the notes which you did not understand.

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming these are not frivolous workshops. In a large university, often one department doesn't really know what the others are doing and schedules are difficult if you want to learn stuff from multiple departments. So if these are "serious" workshops, you can be a bit accommodating. Especially since this is not an overly full class.

You don't want this to be a "bad example" though, that leads to many other people requesting to miss lectures with mandatory attendance.

So what you could so is give them a reading list that should cover the material you'll be doing in that lecture, that they'll have to do in their own time. It shouldn't be any less work than just attending your lecture. Encourage them to stop by during your office hours if they have questions, but only if they've done the reading first.

Comment: These are the workshops not explicitly recommended by department. But, students are interested to attend. That's good.

Answer (score 5):

Two thoughts:

(1) You may be under contractual obligation to hold scheduled classes. (If so, you may want to point this out to the students if they become insistent that you cancel.)

(2) It may not be fair to other students in the class to let a few students get to, in effect, cancel a class.

I would tell the students that it is fine for them to attend the workshop, but they are responsible for the material they missed.

Comment: I am not in the category of (1). As most answers suggest here: I will go with (2).

Answer (score 3):

An easy way around the problem is to record the lecture on camera.

Comment: This is a good idea. One caveat, though: the OP should make sure that everyone who might appear in the recording consents to being recorded.

Comment: Maybe easy, but maybe not. And maybe more or less valuable depending on how the lecture is run. Harder for interactive work as the "focus" needs to change and the sound quality becomes critical (and hard to track).

Comment: @Buffy In my university we had an extra camera team for that. The professors could order it when necessary. Usually that was don for the largest lectures.

Comment: So, easy for you in some situations, but not for all.

Comment: @yar We don't have a proper team for recording lectures.

Answer (score 0):

Workshops are shorter and therefore can be opened more frequently. Main lectures for a class are more important. I see this as a lack of or correct prioritization and/or time administration; young people tend to be impulsive, comfortable childish and kind of wild, demand that they make sure the workshop is higher priority and can't be opened some other time.
Edit: discuss with them how/why is important that workshop and the lecture, I think a common solution is better than a unilateral one.

Comment: On the other hand, workshops sometimes offer a rare opportunity to work with an expert or on things that, while important, don't warrant a full course.

Comment: That is covered in my previous post: "demand that they make sure the workshop is higher priority and can't be opened some other time."

Comment: "Workshops are shorter and therefore can be be opened more frequently" - the second part of this is definitely **not** true for what is referred to as a "workshop" in my field.

Answer (score 0):

A good teacher should be more concerned about conveying knowledge than feeding their own ego.
In this case the fact that you are considering moving your lectures for them makes you sound like a good teacher. 
I'd say 4/20 is a pretty significant number. Maybe check with the other 16 students for their availability before you decide to move it.